# Troubles with implementation of cooley FFT

Tags: c, fft

I am doing a convolution of two integer signals with the help of FFT, but somehow I can't get it right. I am not sure if my implementation of FFT is correct. Especially the math part.

big edit:
I posted all the code now. My apologies for not starting with it. I was sure the error was only in FFT part, but there might be more problems I overlooked. I know the code is messy and not clean. Everything is a bit fragmented and can be programmed in a simpler and cleaner way, but I was testing bit by bit. As for input it reads two signals from the command line. build up as a number indicating how big the signal is and the signal presented as an integer array e.q 2: [1,-1] and 10: [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]. It should then do a convolution on the signals by performing a FFT on both of them then do bit wise multiplication. With a inverse FFT on the resulting signal. Printing it again with the length and then the array consiting of integers. The printing itself is correct, but the values in the resulting array is not correct. I hope it is all a bit clearer now again my apologies and thank you for your help so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h> 
#include <complex.h>

double PI;

int *readSignal(int *len) {    //reads the signal
    int *x;
    char c;
    scanf("%d:", len);
    x = calloc(*len, sizeof(int));
    do c = getchar(); while (c != '[');
    if (len > 0) {
       scanf("%d", &x[0]);
       for (int i=1; i < *len; i++) scanf(",%d", &x[i]);
    }
    do c = getchar(); while (c != ']');
    return x;
}

void printSignal(int len, int *x) { //prints the signal
    printf("%d: [", len);
    if (len > 0) {
        printf("%d", x[0]);
        for (int i=1; i < len; i++) 
            printf(",%d", x[i]);
        }
        printf("]\n");
    }

void *padSignal(int len, int lenSig, int *x) {  //ensures that the signal is of size 2^n by padding it with 0's
    int *padded;
    padded = calloc(len, sizeof(int));
    for (int i=0; i < lenSig; i++) {
        padded[i] = x[i];
    }
    return padded;
}

void fft(double complex signal[], int length, int power) {
    if (length == 1) {
        return;
    }
    double complex *signalODD = calloc((length/2+1), sizeof(double complex));
    double complex *signalEVEN = calloc((length/2+1), sizeof(double complex));
    int index1 = 0;
    int index2 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(i % 2 ==0) {
            signalEVEN[index1] = signal[i];
            index1++;
        }
        else {
            signalODD[index2] = signal[i];
            index2++;
        }
    }
    fft(signalEVEN,length/2, power+1);
    fft(signalODD,length/2, power+1);
    for(int i = 0; i<length/2-1; i++) {
        signal[i] = signalEVEN[i] + cexp((I*2*PI*i)/length)*signalODD[i];
        signal[i+length/2] = signalEVEN[i]-cexp((I*2*PI*i)/length)*signalODD[i];
    }
    free(signalODD);
    free(signalEVEN);
}

void ifft(double complex signal[], int length, int power) {
    if (length == 1) {
        return;
    }
    double complex *signalODD = calloc((length/2+1), sizeof(double complex));
    double complex *signalEVEN = calloc((length/2+1), sizeof(double complex));
    int index1 = 0;
    int index2 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(i % 2 ==0) {
            signalEVEN[index1] = signal[i];
            index1++;
        }
        else {
            signalODD[index2] = signal[i];
            index2++;
        }
    }
    fft(signalEVEN,length/2, power+1);
    ifft(signalODD,length/2, power+1);
    for(int i = 0; i<length/2-1; i++) {
        signal[i] = signalEVEN[i] + cexp((I*-2*PI*i)/length)*signalODD[i];
        signal[i+length/2] = signalEVEN[i]-cexp((I*-2*PI*i)/length)*signalODD[i];
    }
    free(signalODD);
    free(signalEVEN);
}


int checkPowerofTwo(double len) { //checks for the closed power of 2
    double x = 1;
    while(len > pow(2,x)) {
        x++;
    }
    return pow(2,x);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int lenH, *H;
  int lenX, *X;
  int *paddedX;
  int *paddedH;
  double length;
  H=readSignal(&lenH); //reads in the signal H
  X=readSignal(&lenX); //reads in signal X

  length = lenH+lenX-1;
  paddedH=padSignal((length),lenH,H); //pads the signal to the length
  paddedX=padSignal((length),lenX,X); // pads the signal to the length

  double complex *signalX = calloc(length, sizeof(double complex)); //creats a complex signal X and fills it with paddedX
  for (int i = 0; i<length; i++) {
      signalX[i] = paddedX[i];
  }
  double complex *signalH = calloc(length, sizeof(double complex)); // same for H
  for (int i = 0; i<length; i++) {
      signalH[i] = paddedH[i];
  }
  fft(signalX, length, 1); //performs the fast fourier transform on X
  fft(signalH,length, 1); // performs the fast fourier transfom on H
  double complex *signalY = calloc(length, sizeof(double complex)); //makes complex signal Y
  for (int i = 0; i<length; i++) { //performs the convolution
      signalY[i] = signalX[i]*signalH[i];
  }
  ifft(signalY, length,1);

  int *output = calloc(length, sizeof(int)); //creates the final output signal
  for (int i = 0; i<length; i++) {
      output[i] = creal(signalY[i]);
  }
  printSignal(length,output);

  free(signalX);
  free(signalH);
  free(signalY);
  free(H);
  free(X);
  free(paddedH);
  free(paddedX);
  free(output);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question describes a problem with convolution but shows code only for FFT and inverse FFT. No diagnosis of errors in the convolution can be made since it is not shown.

Comment: I omitted it because from my understanding it is pairwise multiplication, but here is that part  
    for (int i = 0; i<lenght; i++) { //performs the convolution
       signalY[i] = signalX[i]*signalH[i];
      }

Comment: Show a [mcve], including input data, for at least one of the cases you say does not work.

Comment: Please show a complete program that can be compiled and run with no changes.

Comment: OP: please do not post code in a comment.  Rather post it as part of the question

Answer (score 2):

In:

```
if(i % 2 ==0 && i != 0)
```

Why do you exclude `i == 0`? Change that to `if(i % 2 ==0)` in both `fft` and `ifft`.

In both `fft` and `ifft`, the line:

```
for(int i = 0; i<lenght/2-1; i++) {
```

should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i<lenght/2; i++) {
```

In `ifft`, the recursion accidentally uses `fft`:

```
fft(signalEVEN,lenght/2, power+1);
fft(signalODD,lenght/2, power+1);
```

Change those to `ifft`.

The `calloc` calls do not need this much space:

```
calloc((lenght/2 + 1), sizeof(double complex));
```

That can be:

```
calloc((lenght/2), sizeof(double complex));
```

Also, the proper spelling of is “length”.

With those fixed, the `fft` and `ifft` routines appear to work for some superficial cases.

Comment: When I change the size of the calloc I get an assertion error. Is there some other error? When I leave the calloc and change the others I do not get a different answer. input signal 1: 3: [1,0,1], signal 2:  5: [1,1,0,1,1]. The expected output is 7: [1,1,1,2,1,1,1] and my output is: 7: [2,0,0,1,0,0,0]. Not sure how the values change so much. but so far thank you for your help